# Grub command line appear after updating Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I have done a software update for ubuntu today after restart I keep on getting grub prompt, and when I try to run "boot" it says that I need to set the kernel first I have looked online and they have recommended the following solution :

```
grub- ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (proc)

This lists disks and partitions on the disks. One of these partitions holds your Linux system. Say it is (hd0,gpt2). Then do:

grub- set root=(hd0,gpt2)
grub- linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic root=/dev/sda2

Replace (hd0,gpt2), the version number and the partition (/dev/sda2) by what is valid for your system. In the case of vmlinuz you can just type vmlinuz- and press Tab.

grub- initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
grub- boot

should now boot up your system.
```

I couldn't follow this cuz Im not sure how to find my vmlinuz version number same with initrd.img
Is there any other solutions to fix this problem or another way to find the version of vmlinuz and initrd

Comment: I had the same problem, this might help you-- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing Read from "Reinstalling GRUB 2"

Comment: Try just using the links vmlinuz and initrd.img (no version numbers). Those should link to the latest versions.